# App crashes when a button is clicked

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I am trying to store the data entered by user to MySQL database using PHP in my android app. But whenever the button is clicked, i receive this message "Unfortunately, [app] has stopped working."

```
public class Register extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText userName, userContact, userAddress, userRequest;
    private Spinner userStore;
    private Button mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //php login script

    //localhost :
    //testing on your device
    //put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    //or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
    // private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/register.php";

    //testing on Emulator:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/callarocket/register.php";

    //testing from a real server:
    //private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/register.php";

    //ids
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_screen);
        Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.StoreSpinner);
        String[] items = new String[]{"NZ Mamak", "Indo Shop", "NZ Supermarket"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

        userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditName);
        userContact = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditContact);
        userAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditAddress);
        userStore = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.StoreSpinner);
        userRequest = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditRequest);

        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new CreateUser().execute();

    }

    class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Request...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = userName.getText().toString();
            String usercontact = userContact.getText().toString();
            String useraddress = userAddress.getText().toString();
            String userstore = userStore.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String userrequest = userRequest.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userContact", usercontact));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userAddress", useraddress));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userStore", userstore));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userRequest", userrequest));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                //Posting user data to script
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // full json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success element
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

And here is my JSONParser code.

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // Extract data from the response.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // Open an inputStream with the data content.
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
            String line = null;

            // Build the string until null.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Close the input stream.
            is.close();
            // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // Return the JSON Object.
        return jObj;

    }


    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

And here is the logcat

```
02-25 11:25:36.224    2445-2460/com.example.user.callarocket D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
02-25 11:25:36.228    2445-2445/com.example.user.callarocket D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c43550, tid 2445
02-25 11:25:36.271    2445-2445/com.example.user.callarocket D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
02-25 11:25:36.373    2445-2460/com.example.user.callarocket D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c438d0, tid 2460
02-25 11:25:36.423    2445-2460/com.example.user.callarocket I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-25 11:25:36.457    2445-2460/com.example.user.callarocket D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-25 11:25:36.500    2445-2460/com.example.user.callarocket W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-25 11:25:36.500    2445-2460/com.example.user.callarocket W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xae1eb880, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-25 11:25:48.014    2445-2460/com.example.user.callarocket W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-25 11:25:48.014    2445-2460/com.example.user.callarocket W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5b6d2a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-25 11:25:48.303    2445-2460/com.example.user.callarocket D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa6cb7580 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa6c43c60
02-25 11:25:59.147    2445-2465/com.example.user.callarocket D/request!﹕ starting
02-25 11:25:59.207    2445-2460/com.example.user.callarocket W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-25 11:25:59.207    2445-2460/com.example.user.callarocket W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xae1f3be0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-25 11:25:59.281    2445-2465/com.example.user.callarocket E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Posted of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-25 11:25:59.299    2445-2465/com.example.user.callarocket E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.user.callarocket, PID: 2445
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.user.callarocket.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:128)
            at com.example.user.callarocket.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:85)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-25 11:25:59.599    2445-2460/com.example.user.callarocket W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-25 11:25:59.599    2445-2460/com.example.user.callarocket W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xae1f3e60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-25 11:26:00.172    2445-2445/com.example.user.callarocket E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.user.callarocket.Register has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2dbde5f6 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
            at com.example.user.callarocket.Register$CreateUser.onPreExecute(Register.java:99)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.example.user.callarocket.Register.onClick(Register.java:81)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

After Log.i("DATA",json) is added

```
02-25 12:24:16.222    2750-2765/com.example.user.callarocket D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
02-25 12:24:16.225    2750-2750/com.example.user.callarocket D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c3e550, tid 2750
02-25 12:24:16.259    2750-2750/com.example.user.callarocket D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
02-25 12:24:16.366    2750-2765/com.example.user.callarocket D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c3e6f0, tid 2765
02-25 12:24:16.405    2750-2765/com.example.user.callarocket I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-25 12:24:16.433    2750-2765/com.example.user.callarocket D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-25 12:24:16.462    2750-2765/com.example.user.callarocket W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-25 12:24:16.462    2750-2765/com.example.user.callarocket W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c118a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-25 12:24:24.841    2750-2765/com.example.user.callarocket W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-25 12:24:24.842    2750-2765/com.example.user.callarocket W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5e39720, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-25 12:24:25.095    2750-2765/com.example.user.callarocket D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa6cb2580 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa6c3eab0
02-25 12:24:33.820    2750-2768/com.example.user.callarocket D/request!﹕ starting
02-25 12:24:33.862    2750-2765/com.example.user.callarocket W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-25 12:24:33.863    2750-2765/com.example.user.callarocket W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5605140, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-25 12:24:34.027    2750-2768/com.example.user.callarocket E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Posted of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-25 12:24:34.028    2750-2768/com.example.user.callarocket E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.user.callarocket, PID: 2750
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.user.callarocket.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:128)
            at com.example.user.callarocket.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:85)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-25 12:24:34.335    2750-2765/com.example.user.callarocket W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-25 12:24:34.335    2750-2765/com.example.user.callarocket W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5af7e00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-25 12:24:36.361    2750-2750/com.example.user.callarocket I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 106 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-25 12:24:36.754    2750-2750/com.example.user.callarocket E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.user.callarocket.Register has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2dbde5f6 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
            at com.example.user.callarocket.Register$CreateUser.onPreExecute(Register.java:99)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.example.user.callarocket.Register.onClick(Register.java:81)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: As in log `Value Posted of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` so what value getting in `json = sb.toString();` line?

Comment: How do I check what value getting in json = sb.toString() ? @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: use log.i("DATA",json); and check logcat

Comment: i got this Error:(129, 20) error: no suitable method found for i(String,JSONObject)
method Log.i(String,String,Throwable) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Log.i(String,String) is not applicable
(actual argument JSONObject cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion) @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: pass `json` instead of `jObj`  like `json = sb.toString();log.i("DATA",json);`

Comment: it seems that the logcat is too long to be posted here @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: done. please check @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: Add `log.i("DATA","json data is :: "+json);` and please post full log

Comment: you mean Log.i("DATA","json data is :: "+json); right ? log.i doesnt work. @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference @Budius do you have any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: that's a NullPointerException, You solve it just like you solve every single other null pointer exception. You put a breakpoint a few lines before and go moving one by one until you find which object is null

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new CreateUser().execute();

    }
```

here you have to use which button is clicked. normally we use

```
switch(v.getId())
{
    case your button id :
              //Button function

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, which is java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using a parser to parse the string and then cast it to a `JSONObject` like so -

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

Object obj = parser.parse(json);
JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;

return jsonObj;
```

Comment: Should I do this in JSONParser.java or Register.java ?

Comment: In `JSONParser.java`. Right about here - 

// try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

            Object obj = parser.parse(json);
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    return jsonObj;